# "Your last flag was declined" Warning, but question was put on hold for the exact reason

Tags: support

I flagged [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41309/stream-data-from-pc-to-raspberry-pi-over-wifi), as "unclear what you are asking"

The question **was closed as "unclear what you are asking"** but now when I tried to raise another flag on a post it warned me with:

> Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this
>   post!

I'm confused, the question was put on hold for the exact reason that I flagged it, is this just a mistake? Also, is it anything bad or just a standard warning?

[image]

Comment: IMHO the word "review" is a little confusing (on its own at least) - it tends to suggest that you can go and "edit" the flag to perhaps change it to become acceptable afterwards.  In this context it actually means, "please review why it was declined as repeated declinations may make it hard or impossible to raise further flags - this is an advisory for that and is to encourage you to *only* bring things to Moderators'  attention [not sure if that is for ALL flag actions!] that they would wish/need to act upon."

Comment: I don't generally see any action taken in response to any comment tags I have done.  Some comments are not constructive, others borderline offensive, yet nothing happens as a result of flagging them.  But I have never tried flagging a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close flags push the question to Close Review queue. If none of reviewers there vote to close, and two vote to Leave Open, the review ends and the flag is declined.

*However*, the question may still be closed if someone who shares your point of view (namely, that the question is unclear) comes across it. Which is what happened.

A declined flag is not a disaster. The warning you saw is standard, and is [documented here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405). It will go away when your next flag is marked helpful, unless you have more declined flags.

Comment: Isn't a close flag 'disputed' if normal users vote to 'Leave Open'? I believe the flag was only declined in this case because [the review was done by a moderator](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review/close/30561).

Comment: Close flags can get declined by review as well, as [stated by an employee here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284872)

Answer (score 5):

If I may say, I completely agree with *a declined flag is not a disaster*. I have quite a few declined flags myself... So do not worry.

On the other hand I'd like to point out that your participation in the site, both in contributing content and in the housekeeping-work including voting, reviewing, editing is highly appreciated. If that particular close vote was not shared at first by two other users (being part of the close review queue) that does not mean it was in vain. Just keep up flagging and editing to improve the site.

Comment: Will do, boss! haha